# Linux Supported Webcam for OpenCV

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ubuntu, webcam

I would like to buy a webcam to use for computer vision. It should cost no more than $35, preferably around $20, and have high resolution and low sensor noise. a 1920x1080 sensor would be ideal. It must also be usable in OpenCV on Ubuntu, or another Linux distribution.

My research has led me to the [A4TECH PK-900H](http://www.a4tech.com/w_product.asp?cid=229&scid=&id=872), which is quite cheap, but I don't know if it supports Ubuntu or not. Are there any high quality webcams that support Ubuntu, or another Linux distribution, and costs around $20?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Hardware Recommendations. Unfortunately, "Will [x] work with [certain software]" is classified as tech support, and not on topic for this site. Questions for this site usually go more like "I want to do [tasks], so I'll need something with [x, y and z requirements] that works with [certain software]". As it stands you might be able to ask your current question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) (I'm not sure), but you can also rephrase your question a little (add requirements and budget) to make it a good fit for this site.

Comment: So, for example, If you want to use it for computer vision, your requirements would be high resolution and low noise, and you'd also need it to work with Ubuntu or another linux distro. Would that be about right?

Comment: @Alpha3031 Yes, That is what I want. I want to use it with computer vision and its price is $22 with HD1080 while the price of logitech c310 is $33 with HD720P

Comment: I'm assuming that you're in the US?

Comment: [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968399/camera-suggestion-for-machine-vision-with-opencv) might be relevant.

Comment: I don't actually know too much about webcams, so hopefully someone with more experience will take over. We are a beta site, so unfortunately we won't have as large a user base as some of the larger sites. :(

Comment: Alright. Thank you @Alpha3031. No problem. Lets hope. You have taught me how to write a question and I am grateful for that. :) I am not from US, I am from Pakistan.

Comment: You're looking for something that follows the [UVC 1.1 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class).  As a rule of thumb, anything that claims "driverless" MacOSX or Windows 7 support is likely to work on Linux.

Comment: The support guy from A4TECH said that this cam is plug and play on windows but he is not sure about ubuntu. However, my research says that this cam is not UVC complaint. @Mark